# External URL to Open Android Application and Load on WebView

Tags: android, url, webview, load, external

I have WebView Android Application
I was wondering if it's possible to have a URL 
that loads specific page on my webview Android Application

when i click on my domain URL it open the Android Application
but it doesn't go the clicked URL
it just start the Splash Activity then Main Activity

how to make the application webview load this url if i choose to the open the url using the application?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Add the following code to **OnCreate**

> Intent intent = getIntent();
>
> final Uri dataUri = intent.getData();

**onCreate** & **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**
and load the url on the Webview using

> view.loadUrl(dataUri.toString());